# How do I query the latest save progress of a list of users. (php/html)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a register and login site where people can click save progress on a form and it inserts a new row with their session id in column 2 as (user_id).

I also have an admin login where I can see their entries but it shows a list all their saves.

I wonder if you could help me figure out a query to list all the latest save progresses of each unique person? like (id,user_id,name,score): (3,3,bob, score 5) (6,4,sam, score 30) without showing all saves of a user's past saves like:
(1,3,bob, score 5) (2,4,sam, score 30) (3,3,bob, score 5) (4,4,sam, score 30)
I need the latest save of each user.

Like the latest id of a distinct list of user_id. Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select user_id,name,score from your_table where (user_id,id) in (select user_id,max(id) from your_table group by user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the below formats for your  tables

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `user_name` varchar(200) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_score` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_score` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Please try executing the below sql select query for retrieving latest score for each user

```
SELECT u . * ,s.user_score,s.id  FROM user u JOIN user_score s ON u.user_id =  s.user_id   WHERE id  IN (SELECT MAX( id )  FROM user_score GROUP BY user_id)
```